# How to pass param to execve to execute cat a file in x64 Asm?

Tags: assembly, c, shellcode, x86-64

I want `execve("/bin/cat",["/bin/cat","/test/file"],NULL)`.

Here is my asm

```
xor %rdx, %rdx 
push %rdx

sub $0x16, %rsp
movb $0x2f, 7(%rsp)
movl $0x2f6e6962, 8(%rsp)
movl $0x746163, 12(%rsp)
leaq 7(%rsp), %rdi

pushq %rdx

push %rdi

mov %rsp, %rsi

movb $0x3b, %al 
syscall
```

This asm, I can get only `execve("/bin/cat",["/bin/cat"],NULL) only.

How can I pass param '/test/file' in rsi?

Comment: regarding: `execve("/bin/cat",["/bin/cat","/test/file",NULL)`  the '[' is an invalid character in the second parameter.

Comment: Suggest: when using `gcc` to compile, to use the `-S` option on a C source file.  This will result in a file containing the assembly instructions needed to perform the `execve()` function.   Then copy the needed instructions into your file

Comment: @user3629249 I forgot "]", fast type. I edited. I will try your suggestion. Thank

Answer (score 1):

[execve specification](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) says:

> Both argv and envp must be terminated by a NULL pointer.

but from your question it seems, that you forgot about it; you want to call it like this:

```
execve("/bin/cat", ["/bin/cat","/test/file", NULL], NULL)
```

If it still doesn't work, here is the working code in C. You can then follow @user3629249's suggestion and use `gcc -S nameOfProgram` to get the assembly generated, or just compile it and see the output of `objdump -d nameOfProgram`.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char* argv[3] = {"/bin/cat", "/test/file", NULL};
    execve("/bin/cat", argv, NULL);
}
```